# Prove $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists $\implies \lim_{x\to a} f(x^2)$ exists

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

Want to prove rigorously (if possible, since I was not able to think of any counter-example) that  $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists $\implies \lim_{x\to a} f(x^2)$ exists.  (I also have a feeling that the limits equate.)

I started with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = l$ which states that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 \forall x:0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-l| < \epsilon$.

Now I want to show that $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists \delta>0 \forall x:0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x^2)-l_1| < \epsilon$ where $l_1 \in \mathbb{R}$.

I've got no clue how to continue.  All help is appreciated.

As an additional note: I believe the converse ($\lim_{x\to a} f(x^2)$ exists $\implies \lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ exists) is not true as $f(x)=\frac{|x|}{x}$ is a counter-example.

Edit: A counter-example was found for the statement but I was wondering whether it is true for $a = 0$?  So in other words, I would like to prove or disprove the statement $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists $\implies \lim_{x\to 0} f(x^2)$ exists

Comment: The claim is false if $f$ doesn't have a limit at $a^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false, as evidenced by the choices $a=2$ and $f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \leq 4 \\ x+1, & x>4.\end{cases}$

Comment: Right.  I was then wondering if it was true if a = 0?

Comment: Well that's a different question.

Comment: Yea let me edit that on sorry about that

Comment: You asked a question, got a good answer. Please don't change it now. You can ask a new question if you want.

Comment: @SaranWrap I don't think that's fair, you should post a new question.

Comment: Alright thats fair sorry about that

Comment: Anyway, do you know how to define a limit using sequences? You can try using it for the case $a=0$. If $x_n$ is a sequence of non-zero real numbers which converges to $0$, then what happens to the sequence $f(x_n^2)$?

Comment: @Mark No I'm not familiar with that method, however I can try looking into it.

Comment: Alright, then you can work with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, it's also easy. For a given $\epsilon$ there is some $\delta_0$ such that $|x|<\delta_0$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. So now simply take $\delta=\sqrt{\delta_0}$. If $|x|<\delta$ then $|x^2|<\delta_0$ and hence $|f(x^2)-L|<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

It is always true for $a=0$ and $a=1$ otherwise just assume a discontinuous function at $x=a^2$.